# Set the channel_priority in Conda environment.yaml

Tags: python, conda, environment

Is it possible to set the `channel_priority` to `strict` when creating an environment using the yaml file? For example:

```
name: my_environment
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python
  - geopandas
  - rasterio
```

Comment: this does not seem to be implemented at the moment: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8675

Comment: It is possible to set channels for each package, e.g., `conda-forge::python`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One additional note is that a specified channel for a given package does not need to be listed in the `channels` section. I find this safer as it does not risk to (re-)install some other package from unexpected channel.

So, for example:

```yaml
channels:
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - python =3.8
  - ...
  # specifically from conda-forge (but only those):
  - conda-forge::nbsphinx
```

Instead of:

```yaml
# NO!
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge

dependencies:
  - python =3.8
  - ...
  - conda-forge::nbsphinx
```

Importantly, this seems to install **only** the specified packages from `conda-forge`, and it doesn't try to (re-)install `conda-forge` versions of packages that are in the dependency graph of those, but are already available (perhaps with a slightly less cutting-edge version) from `pkgs/main`.

Comment: "this seems to install only the specified packages from conda-forge, and it doesn't try to (re-)install conda-forge versions of packages that are in the dependency graph of those" -- Unfortunately, this will stop working once `channel_priority: strict` becomes the default in Conda 5. Namely, with `channel_priority: strict` enabled, when I try to install a conda-forge package using your method and one of its dependencies is already installed (from `defaults`), I end up getting a conflict, no matter whether the installed version is actually compatible with the desired version.

Comment: That being said, I really like your suggestion as it prevents horror stories like https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610 . (Consider that `defaults` is run by a well-known company whereas `conda-forge` does not even provide contact details of anyone in charge. What's worse, several hundred people seem to have access to the `conda-forge` repository.)

Comment: The closest official documentation I could find on this feature is https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually . Is there anything better?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to [merv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570918/merv).
A workaround is to specify the channel for each package:

```
name: my_environment
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - conda-forge::python
  - conda-forge::geopandas
  - conda-forge::rasterio
```

Comment: How to I specify a local channel for a given package. Adding the file:// path under channels works but not when i specify it per package. conda appears to look for a url

Comment: What would be the prefix for the default channel?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a full replacement for channel priority, because it only affects the listed packages. E.g. it cannot affect the *dependencies* of those packages. E.g. if "geopandas" depends on numpy then one has to also list numpy like this in order to force the conda-forge version to be used.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, no I don't think it is possible to add `channel_priority` to the environment file. Maybe raise this as [a Conda issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues) (if it isn't there already ;).

Something else worth trying would be adding `defaults` to the channel listing explicitly with lower priority like so...

```yaml
name: my_environment
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
  - geopandas
  - rasterio
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way is to first create the empty environment and set the channel priority to strict, then install the packages from the spec file:

```
conda create new_env
conda activate new_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda env update --name new_env --file env.yml
```

Note: if using a .txt spec file instead of .yml then replace the last line with

```
conda install --name new_env --file env.txt
```

reference doc:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#id13

Comment: I think that first line should be `conda create -n new_env`

Comment: the purpose of putting this in a YAML file is so that the user does not have to run these command manually as you have shown, which can easily lead to missed steps and an improperly configured environment

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that there simply is no way to do this in YAML (as of time of writing now)